# not sure about the most efficient way to filter a set of json arrays with jq when some keys are only present in a few arrays - //?

Tags: arrays, json, null, filtering, jq

just started using jq to try and consolidate a few keys that are in a much larger json file piped from curl.

- the following command outputs the desired information from all 10 records as expected:

`curl http://localhost/test.json | jq -r '.array[] | {name: .firstname, job: .position, location: .sites[]? .officename}'`

- 2 of the records have an additional key, which is absent from the others. adding that key to the command results in keys being returned only for those two records. removing the `?` from `.contact[]?` errors out with `jq: error: Cannot iterate over null`:

`curl http://localhost/test.json | jq -r '.array[] | {name: .firstname, job: .position, location: .sites[]? .officename, phone: .contact[]? .number}'`

- currently working around this by using the // operator as shown below. is there a more efficient or recommended way of using jq in this manner?

`curl http://localhost/test.json | jq -r '.array[] | {name: .firstname, job: .position, location: .sites[]? .officename, phone: .contact[]? .number} // {name: .firstname, job: .position, location: .sites[]? .officename}'`

thanks

---edit: adding a short example of test.json below for reproducibility:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "array": [{
         "firstname": "Nobody",
         "lastname": "Nothing",
         "sites": [{
            "officename": "Site1",
            "city": "City"
         }],
         "position": "Test1"
      },
      {
         "firstname": "Anybody",
         "lastname": "Anything",
         "sites": [{
            "officename": "Site2",
            "city": "City2"
         }],
         "position": "Test2",
         "contact": [{
            "number": "123-456-7890",
            "email": "test@test.com"
         }]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and to jq. It would greatly help if you could provide one or more illustrative but succinct samples of the JSON you have in mind as per the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: @peak added JSON sample to original post - thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for a variant of your solution along the lines of:

```
.array[]
| {name: .firstname, job: .position, location: .sites[]? .officename}
  +  ({phone: .contact[].number}? // null)
```

(The point being that adding null to a JSON object yields the same object.)

This variant of course comes with the same caveats as the original. In particular, the use of all but the first array iterators might be problematic.